# sonar plugin issue: The plugin [cxx] does not support Java 1.8.0_212

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I'm using SonarQube to perform scans on two of my projects. One of them requires the CXX plugin for a complete analysis. However, after installing the plugin on my instance, the other project(should be run with java 1.6.x) encountered the following issue. I'm seeking assistance in finding a solution to this problem.

```
21:23:07 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven: sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168: sonar (default-cli) on project nxdh-parent: The plugin [cxx] does not support Java 1.8.0_212: org/sonar/plugins/cxx/CxxPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```